# Googlebot visit but no cache update - why?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot

I have made a new plain vanilla HTML website. I have been making regular modifications to it on an almost daily basis. The site is hosted by hostmonster and as part of their service they offer "awstats" to let you know assorted details of visitors to the site. One thing is puzzling me. According to awstats, a "robot/spider" calling itself "Googlebot" visited my site as recently as today (28th June 2011), but when I find my site on google (e.g. by searching for "full reserve banking") the cache is dated only the 5th June. I always thought that a visit from the google robot was synonymous with a cache update. Am I wrong? Or have I accidentally put something in the site telling google that nothing has been updated?

**EDIT:** It seems a moderator has removed the name of my website, so there is now no chance that anyone could check out if I had made some error on my site :-( ... but anyway, in answer to paulmorriss' question, here is what aw stats was telling me:
[image]

Comment: Did it visit the home page today?

Comment: FYI, we tend to remove websites from questions as it would make the question too localized. By removing it the question benefits anyone with the same problem.

Comment: @John Conde: I don't get your logic - if it turned out I had some stupidity in my HTML that was causing the problem, then this question could prevent other people from making the same stupid error. There is nothing "local" about plain HTML. If the answers given turn out to have nothing to do with the quirks of my HTML, then how much harm is being done by including the site name?

Comment: if it was a coding issue I would have left it in place. But unless you are [explicitly telling Google not to cache your website](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html) (which you haven't done) then this isn't a coding issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because Googlebot visits your site it doesn't mean something is going to change in Google's search results soon after. Google's cache is not updated daily and is known for taking quite some time to update itself.

There is no set timetable for when Google will update its cache but I suspect it works a lot like how they add newer pages to the index. Site like StackOverflow will see an updated cache and new pages indexed quickly. Lesser sites will see a delay between the cache being updated and newer pages being added.

There's nothing you can do about it other then to be patient.

Comment: They say they take a snapshot each time they visit http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/features_list.html#cached. However they can do what they like and do seem to.